# Action Script 3. Change animations when character moving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, character

I'm creating simple flash game. I need to change animations when character moving. For example when going, running, jumping, attacking etc. I have different animations. Just I don't know how to add them correctly?

In Library I have created my character, It named "Hero" As Linkage too "Hero". I need double click It and in Hero's timeline create new Layers with names run, walk, attack, etc... and then put here animations? Or I need in Library create name and As Linkage "HeroRun", "heroAttack" etc...?

As I know I need to use later something like `Hero.gotoAndPlay(run);` but this doesn't work for me. Sorry for these newbie questions, but I really need your help, thank you.

For example this is my part of code for turn left:

```
    if(left){
                Hero.x_speed = -walkspeed;
                setDirection(1);
                Hero.gotoAndPlay(run);// I don't know how to use It correctly
}
```

**UPDATE**

How It looks now:
Created MovieClip character Hero

[image: Character]

Created layers hit and going

[image: layers]

And for now I need to use `Hero.gotoAndStop("hit");` if want to see "hit" animation?

**UPDATE 2**
All right, I did that, but now I have problem there is no animations only change image after I use `Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");`, but here must be animation. Here is photo how attack MovieClip looks like:
[image: movieclip]

Here' my Hero screenshot.It have 2 keyframes Attack and Going.

[image: Hero screen shot]

And here is hero > going timeline's screenshot:

[image: timeline]

**UPDATE:**

Here is my code for space button (jumping character) when It show animation on the ground I have big lags I think that because checking for collisions and when on the air animation playing without lag.

```
    if(Hero.y_speed>0 && myCollisionList.checkCollisions().length > 0 ){
        Hero.y_speed=0;
        Hero.x_speed=0;

        if(space){


            if (ground.hitTestPoint(Hero.x + 28, Hero.y+20, true)){

            Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");
            stop();
            Hero.y_speed = -20;
```

And here is collision list:

```
        var myCollisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList(Hero);
        myCollisionList.addItem(ground);
        myCollisionList.addItem(ground3);
        myCollisionList.addItem(ground5);
        myCollisionList.addItem(ground4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gotoAndPlay()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29) function takes either a frame index (`int`) or a frame label (`String`) parameter, not the name of another movie clip.

What you're trying to do can be accomplished in several ways - in my opinion the simplest is to set up one `MovieClip` that contains all the animations of your character as individual keyframes. You can then label each keyframe with a unique label and then use the [`gotoAndStop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndPlay%28%29)  function to switch between animations.

First, create each character animation as a separate `MovieClip` - you don't need to export these (unless you need to programmatically access them). Once this is done, create a new `MovieClip` and add a keyframe for each of the animations you made. So if your character has 4 animations (for example `walking`, `idle1`, `idle2`, `running`) you'd create 4 keyframes in this clip.

Put each of the animations in one of the keyframes (carefully align them so that when you switch the character won't jump) and then label each keyframe with the appropriate animation name. Export this movie clip from the library. You can label a keyframe by clicking the keyframe in the timeline and then adding a label name in the `Properties` window. Once the frame label is in place, the frame will have a small red flag. Here's a screenshot with the labels in Flash CS 5 (the image is edited to show only relevant parts):

[image: Frame labels added in Flash CS 5 (edited)]

Once this is done, you can now create an instance of your character and set the correct animation state by calling:

```
...
Hero.gotoAndStop("walking");
...
```

You could also use just `Hero.gotoAndStop ( 1 );` if the walking animation is on keyframe 1 but if you change the order of your animations you'd have to update all the code if you use frame indexes. Using frame labels is a lot more flexible.

You need to use `gotoAndStop()` to let Flash stay on the specified keyframe and keep showing the animation in that frame. If you used `gotoAndPlay()` you'd only see the first frame of all state animations as Flash cycles through the key frames.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I updated my question with screen shots and additional question.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Your `hit` and `going` animations shouldn't be in the same `MovieClip` - move them into two separate clips. You'll have two separate timelines then, each with a single layer. After that create a third `MovieClip` with 2 keyframes and label the keyframes themselves `hit` and `going`.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė I edited the answer to explain how to add a keyframe label. What you have right now (in your screenshots) are layer labels - those are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I created for now 3 Movie Clips as you said. "Attack", "Going" and "Hero". In "Hero" I created 2 keyframes (I did It by clicking right mouse button, "Insert Keyframe") and First of It I entered label name - Going, other - Attack. But they are blank is It all right? Or I need to do something more? Now I'm trying Hero.gotoAndStop("going"); nothing happens, my character invisible at all, not appears on the stage.

Comment: And yes, here are now red flags, but they are blank, I don't know how to import data from Going and Attack MovieClips.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė You need to select the appropriate keyframe, grab your `Attack` and `Going` clips from the library and drag it onto the stage. So each keyframe in your `Hero` clip will have 1 movie clip inside it (on the stage).

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but now I have problem, If I use `Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");` only image changes and nothing more, but here must be animation, when I use `Hero.gotoAndStop("going");` the same - show only image without animation. I updated screen shot in my question (Update 2).

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Can you show a screenshot of your `Hero` symbol? What you have now is a single state animation. Your `Hero` clip should have 2 keyframes. One of those would be called `Attack` and would have the the attack animation that you showed in your current screenshot.

Comment: Updated my question with screenshot of the Hero. It have 2 keyframes Going and Attack. If I double click on Hero's image which you see on the screen in timeline appears normal animation.

Comment: Updated my question with screenshot of Hero's > going timeline

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė What you have seems to be correct. If you now drag the Hero symbol on the stage of `Scene 1` (name the instance `_hero`) and add `_hero.gotoAndStop("Going");` to the action panel of the frame, what do you see?

Comment: Yes in this case working fine. But in my code hero I have variable `public var Hero:hero = new hero;` and if I use `Hero.goToAndStop("walking");` doesnt work, just change picture, but no animation... Why when I drag It on the Stage (Scene 1) and add instance name It working fine?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Make sure you use the rigth frame labels. If you named your frame `Going`, that's what you need to use. Frame labels are also case-sensitive, if I remember right.

Comment: Now here are 2 hero's on the screen 1 - original, which is spawned by addChild(Hero); and other as you said - dragged on the stage and It have instance name "_hero). If I use `Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");` It just change image, but not showing animation. and If I use `_hero.gotoAndStop("attack");` - It's working fine, show animation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved problem, there was update_hero function which stopped MovieClip at 1st frame.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė There should be no difference between the two. Dragging something to the stage is the same as adding it through code. Can you post your code that you use to create your `Hero` instance?

Comment: Oh my god, now I have incredible lag when during animation maybe that because with ~100 frames? Possible to avoid lag? Or maybe I need to wait till It loads and later I don't have lag anymore?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Make sure you're not adding the same `Hero` animation more than once. I uploaded a sample .fla file for you at http://pastelink.me/dl/52f61a - take a look at the code in Scene 1. (Scene 1 should only have 1 frame - I accidentally added 3.)

Comment: Thank you for everything. I use now `if(space){ Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");
     stop();` but It loop animation non-stop. How to make that showed animation once?

Comment: And I misunderstood why I have big lags if animation during when Hero staying on the ground or have any collision with stages, If Its flying on the air animations going without any lags... Huh..?

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė I can't tell without seeing a lot more of your code. It sounds like you have some code already in place. This setup is very efficient and ~100 frames is really not much so it's not the reason for your lag. Post that issue as a separate question with an .fla after some debugging. My guess is that some of your code runs too many times and many extra instances are created.

Comment: I updated my question with part of code where space button is clicked, maybe you see any mistakes here, why can I have lag when character staying on the ground during animation and why animation loop non stop.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Please post it as a separate question. This question is already getting very long and it'd be confusing to future readers. You'll also need to provide more detail than what you added - preferably the entire fla file (cut down to minimal size with minimal art). That would make seeing your problem a lot easier.

Comment: Ok, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883530/action-script-3-animation-loop-forever-after-gotoandstop-and-have-lag-during