# Action Script 3. Animation loop forever after gotoAndStop() and have lag during animation when character have collisions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, actionscript, collision-detection

I'm creating simple flash game. I have problem, animation loop forever after I user gotoAndStop() and I have lag when during animation if character have collision with ground or any stage (if character flying on the air don't have any lags)

Here is collision list:

```
var myCollisionList:CollisionList = new CollisionList(Hero);
myCollisionList.addItem(ground);
myCollisionList.addItem(ground3);
myCollisionList.addItem(ground5);
myCollisionList.addItem(ground4);
```

And here is my part of code where jumping with animation.

```
if(Hero.y_speed>0 && myCollisionList.checkCollisions().length > 0 )
{
    Hero.y_speed=0;
    Hero.x_speed=0;

    if(space)
    {
        if (ground.hitTestPoint(Hero.x + 28, Hero.y+20, true))
        {
            Hero.gotoAndStop("attack");
            stop();
            Hero.y_speed = -20;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Screenshot of the map:

[image: map]

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is part of code for move character to left (to right side the same) side, I know Its terrible, but I don't know how to make It better.

*pakopos - name of CollisionList*

*fonas - background*

```
    var pakopos:CollisionList = new CollisionList(Hero);
    pakopos.addItem(ground);
    pakopos.addItem(ground3);
    pakopos.addItem(ground5);
    pakopos.addItem(ground4);

if(left){

    Hero.x_speed = -walkspeed;

    setDirection(1);

    if(pakopos.checkCollisions().length > 0) {

    if (ground5.hitTestPoint(Hero.x - 26, Hero.y-120, true)) {                  
        trace("Touching left side - ground5");
        ground5.x += 0;
        ground4.x += 0;
        ground3.x += 0;
        fonas.x += 0;
        Enemy.x += 0;
        }
    else if (Enemy.hitTestPoint(Hero.x - 26, Hero.y-120, true)) {
        trace("Touching Enemy");
        ground5.x += 0;
        ground4.x += 0;
        ground3.x += 0;
        fonas.x += 0;
        Enemy.x += 0;
        }
    else if (ground3.hitTestPoint(Hero.x - 26, Hero.y-120, true)) {
        trace("Touching left side - ground3");
        ground5.x += 0;
        ground4.x += 0;
        ground3.x += 0;
        fonas.x += 0;
        Enemy.x += 0;
        }
    else if (ground4.hitTestPoint(Hero.x - 26, Hero.y-120, true)) {
        trace("Touching left side - ground4");
        ground5.x += 0;
        ground4.x += 0;
        ground3.x += 0;
        fonas.x += 0;
        Enemy.x += 0;
    }else
    {
        Hero.x_speed = 0; 
        ground5.x += 4;
        ground4.x += 4;
        ground3.x += 4;
        fonas.x += 4;
        Enemy.x += 4;

    }}
    else {
        ground5.x += 4;
        ground4.x += 4;
        ground3.x += 4;
        fonas.x += 4;
        Enemy.x += 4;

    }}
```

Comment: If your code is in a class file (.as), you shouldn't need the `stop()` call. In my other answer it was there because the code was on the timeline and that wraps around.\ sp the code would repeat.

Comment: How big is `ground`? Is it a bitmap or is it a vector image?

Comment: Yes my code is in .as file, so how can I stop It? I need animation only once. And ground is (640x60) bitmap.

Comment: What happens if you replace `if (ground.hitTestPoint(Hero.x + 28, Hero.y+20, true))` with `if(true)`? Is it still lagging? The code you posted seems ok - it doesn't seem like it's the source of your lag. If you only have a few objects on the stage, it shouldn't lag unless there's something in the background. What's your frame rate?

Comment: Here is lag too when during simple "going" animation. That means this with jumping is all right problem is in other place. I don't know about frame rate. I had little lag before too, because something wrong with collisions, as you said before maybe code checking for collisions too many times.

Comment: Check your frame rate then in Flash - if it's too low then screen updates will be slow. For games 30 FPS is minimum but more is recommended, depending on the game.

Comment: What does the `checkCollisions()` function do? If it checks collisions among the items in your collision list then you effectively run collision detection twice every time this code runs. Pixel perfect collision detection is very expensive.

Comment: Frame rate was 40, changed to 100, but the same. When player have collisions game going to slow motion.

Comment: 100 FPS is way too much - browsers limit it to 60 FPS. 40 is an ok number.

Comment: Yes checkCollisions() checks collisions with Hero and objects on the stage (ground3, ground4, ground5). I don't know how can I avoid It.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very cryptic so it's hard to say what's going on without actually debugging it but my guess is that you're checking collisions multiple times every time your posted code runs. You should check the documentation of the `checkCollisions()` function that you use since it seems to return an array of results. It likely gives you all collisions that it found among the objects in the collision list so you don't have to call `hitTestPoint()` directly afterwards.

**Edit**:

I'm not familiar with CDK  that you use in your code but it returns an array of collision results where each result has the colliding objects, their angle and if they're overlapping. For what you're trying to do it seems like an overkill but as I said, I'm not familiar with it - it may be a lot faster then `hitTestPoint()`.

I'd recommend using only one hit test method - either use CDK or use `hitTestPoint()` but not both. Both will give you pixel perfect detection results. If you use CDK, read the documentation on how `checkCollisions()` works. You'd have to do something like this:

```
...
var oResults:Array = pakopos.checkCollisions();
var nCount:int = oResults.length;

if (nCount > 0)
{
    for ( var i:int = 0; i <nCount; i++ )
    {
        var oHit:Object = oResults[i];

        // TODO check `oHit.object1` and `oHit.object2` to see which objects
        // collided and do something based on that
        // You may have multiple results since your hero may collide with
        // 'ground' and 'ground4' at the same time.
    }
}
```

Your collision group (`pakopos`) setup for CDK seems to be off - you won't have to determine if there's a collision between all the objects in your group - I assume you don't care if `ground` collides with `ground4` but you added both to your collision list.

I think (not sure) that `checkCollisions()` tries to check all objects in the group against all other objects. What you need is check one object (`Hero`) against a list of objects (the various ground objects). That's a massive difference between the number of checks. This and your extra calls to `hitTestPoint()` can easily account for your lag.

Comment: pastelink.me/dl/9546d1 Here is link. Script.as is my main code, but I don't know if you will understand my code... And I don't know how to use `checkCollisions()` correctly without `hitTestPoint()`

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I'm not really understood how to use It? Could you write me sample for moving left? For now I used It:     `for ( var i:int = 0; i <nCount; i++ )
    {
        var oHit:Object = oResults[i];
    trace(oResults[i]);
    }}
   }` and It returns `[object Object]
[object Object]` everytime I click "Left arrow"

Comment: And for now will problem if player stay on the ground can't move to left or right, because have collision with the ground.

Comment: @RimantėBaltiejūtė Look ad the CDK.as file in your code - the `findCollisions()` function is what gets called by `checkCollisions()`. You can also post a question to whoever made CDK.